# after Maven job build success, Jenkins displayed failure with failed to parse POM

Tags: maven, jenkins

Background info:

1. I have a simple maven project on Mac using eclipse, doing ui testing.
2. setup jenkins server on localhost:8080  (with latest jenkins version)
3. configure Root POM as where the pom.xml is located locally(/Users/username/eclipse-workspace/ui-test/pom.xml)
4. It can build successfully with maven locally
5. also build successfully on Jenkins

However, after the jenkins shows BUILD SUCCESS, it "Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data" then displays:

"ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/username/.jenkins/workspace/UI-Automation-Job/Users/username/eclipse-workspace/ui-test/pom.xml"

I'd appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
---detailed jenkins log---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 43.119 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-29T17:19:40-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/username/eclipse-workspace/ui-test/pom.xml to ui-test/ui-test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ui-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/username/eclipse-workspace/ui-test/target/ui-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to ui-test/ui-test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ui-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
/Users/username/eclipse-workspace/ui-test/pom.xml is not inside /Users/username/.jenkins/workspace/UI-Automation-Job/Users/username/eclipse-workspace/ui-test/; will archive in a separate pass
/Users/username/eclipse-workspace/ui-test/target/ui-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is not inside /Users/username/.jenkins/workspace/UI-Automation-Job/Users/username/eclipse-workspace/ui-test/; will archive in a separate pass
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/username/.jenkins/workspace/UI-Automation-Job/Users/username/eclipse-workspace/ui-test/pom.xml
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:1849)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.properties.PomPropertiesFinder.findProperties(PomPropertiesFinder.java:50)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoExtractor.extract(MavenInfoExtractor.java:58)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoEnvironment.tearDown(MavenInfoEnvironment.java:42)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:908)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1727)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
channel stopped
....
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error:

> /Users/username/eclipse-workspace/ui-test/pom.xml is not inside
>   /Users/username/.jenkins/workspace/UI-Automation-Job/Users/username/eclipse-workspace/ui-test/;

We can learn Jenkins file to find your pom.xml, Please go through your job configuration and find out where did you input this string `/Users/username/eclipse-workspace/ui-test/pom.xml`

Check below most possible places: `Root POM` and `Archive files`, Recommend to use relative path, but absolute path.

> Jenkins will create a folder on Jenkins Slave(on which you job
>   executing) to place your project source code, stuff generated during
>   job running, etc.

If you use relative path, Jenkins will automatically use Job's workspace folder as parent folder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: After disabling those two options, it still failed.

Comment: Please give your pom.xml and what did you input in `Goals and options` in Jenkins job configuration, And give the setting of `Archiving files` If you added in job's Post Action.

Comment: The `Goals and options` I have is `clean install`. I don't have the `Archive the artifacts` in my menu, as I'm using the latest Jenkins version. I didn't add any Post Action either, thanks.

Comment: The `install` goal will archive your project to a Maven package which includes a jar and your pom.xml.   Did you not use Source Code Management in Jenkins to get the project code to Jenkins Server, but put the code on Jenkins Server manually in advance?

Comment: Thanks @yong, I tried two approaches: [Approach 1]. source code is local: In the "Source Code Management", I selected option "none", because the source code is local. The above mentioned jenkins failure message happened in this approach. [Approach 2]. source code on Github, and select "Git" in the "Source Code Management", the jenkins job succeeded without error message. Please let me know how to make [approach 1] work, when the source code is local, should i configure something in advance before jenkins job run? Thanks.

Comment: You need to copy the project folder: `ui-test` into the Job workspace folder: `/Users/username/.jenkins/workspace/UI-Automation-Job/` on Jenkins server. Then  in `Root POM`, input relative path: `util-test/pom.xml`